# "User can't edit this question" message appeared while editing?

Tags: support, status-completed, editing, suggested-edits

I was editing a question when this happened:

> User can't edit this question

When does this error occur and why?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81701/231828

Comment: How would ik which one is my case?

Comment: Based on the current edits you've recently made, I suspect that you had 5 edits waiting in the queue. The queue has been cleared, so try again now. Please review [this page](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/editing) prior to editing.

Comment: @Fezter is correct too many edits that are queued up for review by the same user.

Comment: @DaminiJain Can you ease up on your trivial edits please.  I've rejected a few as being no improvement and one as actively harming the question.  I didn't see [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/295517/revisions) which got approved but shouldn't have because it harmed the question, i.e changing "sum" to "some" was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

As [pointed out by Luke](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295836/digitize-objects-in-a-lidar-point-cloud), one will find possible reasons why this happened in the Meta Stack Exchange post: [Why is the edit button disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled/81701#81701)

Which reason exactly triggered the message I don't know, but could be what [Fezter suggested](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4935/user-cant-edit-this-question-message-appeared-while-editing#comment9392_4935): five suggested-edits pending review (#3).